# Модуль для поиска в админке в Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, search

Здравствуйте.
Необходим модуль для поиска в админке. 
Описание: пользователей заходит в админку и в форме поиска пишет допустим 'Hello world' и происходит поиск в Content, Taxonomy и других нодах. И при переходе по ссылке попадаешь для редактировании ноды. 
[Модуль 'Find Content'](https://www.drupal.org/project/find_content) не совсем подходит.

По функционалу подходит  [модуль 'Custom Search'](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search) , но если вводить поиск в админке то результаты поиска отображаются во фронтенде и ссылка на Frontend, а не на Backend.

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли похожий модуль как Custom Search, но только для Backend?
Либо можно как нибудь изменить модуль Custom Search чтобы результаты отображались в админке и по ссылке переходить на редактировании ноды?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api + https://www.drupal.org/project/views любые виды поиска и по чём угодно можно сделать.

Честно говоря, у меня было иное представление о терминах Front end и Back end… [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_end_и_back_end](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_end_%D0%B8_back_end)

Answer (score 0):

Нет такого модуля, и не будет! Хочется "серебряную пулю" - пилите сами.

Почему это никто в здравом уме реализовывать не будет, "защита от дурака" так сказать.

- Прежде чем редактировать материал - посмотри его! Поиск выдал результат - перейди, оцени, прийми решение, редактируй.
- Если возникла необходимость не по причине "я так хочу", то вы точно знаете, что будете редактировать, для этого, в панели админа, в разделе "Материалы", вы или сразу найдете нужный, перейдя в нужный "тип материала", и там фильтра работают очень четко, или, если у вас материалы висят в разделе "Опубликовать", вы так же легко сможете это сделать.